# How to scrape a JavaScript website using Python with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape from this website link:
https://www.betbrain.com/baseball/united-states/mlb/

My Python code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

delay=10

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.betbrain.com/baseball/united-states/mlb/')
WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/section/section/nav')))


table_check = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/section/section/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul') #find the table containing games 
body_rows = table_check.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/section/section/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]') #find each indvidual game

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app"]/div/section/section/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul"}
```

When I try running it, it seems to be struggling to find the X_path. Also, I am willing to move away from Xpath if there is an easier/more stable way to select the information.

Comment: Be bit more specific , what exactly you want to scrap from the provided link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code to get the match details :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import pickle

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://www.betbrain.com/baseball/united-states/mlb/")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.MatchesList")))

game_names = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.MatchesList>li a.MatchTitleLink span")

for game in game_names:
   print(game.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, how do you go about finding the CSS selector? Is there a way to copy it in Chrome like with Xpath?

Comment: there are some extension you can use. However I would not recommend to use those extension , I will give some like for css selector :

Comment: You can go through the provided link. just inspect the web page and try to write your own css selector or relative xpath.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of xpaths which are slower and brittle, try using css selectors.

```
driver.get('https://www.betbrain.com/baseball/united-states/mlb/')
time.sleep(5)

parent_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.MatchesListAndHeader > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > ul')

#find all li childs in parent element
child = parent_element.find_elements_by_css_selector('li')

for i in child:
    print(i.text)


driver.quit()
```

This is just a simple script which will get all the text from the table in an unformatted way from the table that is present in the page.

Sample output that I got :

```
24/06/2018 17:05
Boston Red Sox — Seattle Mariners
United StatesMLB 2018
Home
(1.40)
1.46
1xBet
Away
(2.98)
3.10
Mybet
26
4

United States
MLB 2018
Home
(1.40)
1.46
1xBet

Away
(2.98)
3.10
Mybet
24/06/2018 20:07
Los Angeles Angels — Toronto Blue Jays
United StatesMLB 2018
Over
(1.96)
1.96
1xBet
Under
```

Comment: Sauce labs has an excellent tutorial on this .https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is needlessly complicated.
Use CSS selectors. I see you are trying to get the all the match `li`s.
This `li.Match` CSS selector should do it.

`matches = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.Match")`

should get you all the matches.